# Electron: send buffer from main to renderer

Tags: node.js, buffer, electron

In the main process, I have a simple *Uint8Array* and I want to send it to the renderer process.

*sender.send* is converting everything to JSON, so it cannot be used for binary data.

Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: Any reason you cannot encode it in base64, pass it to the renderer, and convert it back there?

Comment: too slow... and inefficient

Comment: how much data are you dealing with? Could you access the source of the data directly from the renderer process instead?

Comment: It will be a lot of data. And that data is made by a C++ Node.js addon. Which outputs classic Node.js Buffers.

Comment: Could you access it directly from the renderer process by ensuring nodeIntegration is on?

Comment: I have no idea... if there's a way, I'm interested

Comment: By default, a renderer process should have access to everything node has to offer. Have you tried doing in a renderer process what you are currently doing in your main process?

Comment: You can access it from remote

Comment: I looked at remote didn't see any clear example how to move a buffer from main to renderer. If you have one or know how, you'll solve my problem.

Comment: Like Shawn says above, try to access the data directly from the Renderer process (the remote module is not a good way to do that).

Comment: but how do I access it directly?

Comment: copy the code where you access it from your main process to your renderer process and see if it works

Comment: @widgg: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @DavidCampos nope, never found a decent way to use the same buffer on client and server side. We went with another solution.

Comment: `remote` module was always meant to be an abstraction over ipc so it's just nicer syntax, it's no different from using `ipcRenderer` itself. And Chromium has no way to open file from file system (it's a browser duh!), so is impossible I guess. Please let us know what solution you went with in the end.

Comment: we simply created a second window with OpenGL to render and it's controlled by the server-side part of the code.

Answer (score 2):

in main.js

```
global.Uint8Array.root = YOUR_JSON;
```

in render js

```
const {remote} = require('electron');
...
console.log(remote.getGobal('Uint8Array').root);
```

Comment: They say `remote` is just an abstraction on top of `ipcRenderer`. Do you know if it doesn't do any weird serialize/unserialize (into base64 and back for example) behind scenes to get that syntax working?